# Physical interpretation of semiconductor band bending to establish thermal equilibrium in PN junction

Tags: electrostatics, semiconductor-physics

My question uses the PN junction simply as a concrete example of band bending establishing thermal equilibrium. Below I state my question first and then provide an overview of my current understanding of the situation to try to clarify the question and provide context.

**My question:**

The band diagram for a material depicts which electron energy levels are possible in a given material. When a silicon PN homojunction is formed and allowed to reach thermal equilibrium, the bands bend, seemingly indicating that throughout the entire material, the allowed electron energy levels are now different. Consider for example the shifting of the band edges on the N side, which implies that a certain energy which used to be inside the bandgap (i.e. between $E_{C1}$ and $E_{C0}$ in my figure below) is now allowed, **even very far away from the junction**, and why this should happen is unclear to me. Maybe my misunderstanding is trying to understand the energy levels in absolute terms when I should only be considering the differences between any two energies.

[image: pn junction diagram]

**My general understanding of the meaning of the band diagram**:

Isolated atoms have discrete allowable energy levels for electrons associated with them. Due to the pauli exclusion principle, as many atoms of a kind are brought closer and closer together to form a solid material, the allowable energy levels split more and more finely (as more and more atoms are brought together). With very many atoms, the allowed discrete energy levels are so numerous and so close that they may be conceptualized as effectively continuous within certain limits, and this is where the idea of continuous energy "bands" comes from. An illustration of this is shown below. $E_C$ is the bottom edge of the nearly-empty band and $E_V$ is the top edge of the nearly-filled band. This should be a material property and not significantly affected by moderate doping or carrier transport, and I think this second part is where some of my confusion is.

[image: band formation]

Comment: You chose to bold-face a comment about the situation very far away from the junction.  Is that the core of the question?  If so, note that in practical cases the resistances in the wires and bulk materials is small enough that there is no significant potential change (i.e., small compared to the potential shift at the junction) along the parts of the circuit.  If you are considering a diode by itself, not in a circuit, don't forget the charge that is induced at the ends of the diode.

Comment: Could you elaborate on induced charge at the ends of the diode for an isolated diode? This isn't something that I've seen covered in books on the subject.

Answer (score 0):

You are mixing different things together. It is a big misunderstanding.

The combination of atomic levels into bands is correct. It being a material property and not much affected by *weak* doping is correct, but mostly definitional (of what it means to be weakly doped).

But the junction is not doing that. What is happening is that when you put two materials into contact, electrons thermally spill from one side to the other, giving rise to an electrostatic, electrochemical potential $\mu$ shift of all the energy levels. Yes, if you want to be technical, this affects the material everywhere, but in practice, you cannot even see the shifting on a big plot just a few layers into each material.

Any good textbook should be covering this concept.

Comment: Thanks for your response. To clarify, I'm not suggesting that the formation of the junction is the same as the formation of energy bands by bringing silicon atoms into a lattice. The reason I brought up the lattice formation is because I think location of the bands along the y axis (electron energy) is determined by the lattice spacing. When the junction is formed, electron diffusion leads to built-in voltage and band bending. If the bands shift (eg) down on N side, then this seems to imply that just the diffusion of electrons shifted all the allowed energies, which is confusing to me.

Comment: Do you understand it now?

Comment: I think the part that's still unclear is why the existence of the built in potential at the junction changes whether or not a state exists at some energy throughout the entire semiconductor material. Possibly what I mean could become clearer with another diagram which I can provide tomorrow (it's very late in my current area).

Comment: What are you even asking about? The net transfer of charge due to thermal diffusion means that there is a rigid shift of all energy levels near the junction. Only near the junction. The rest of the material will, as your first plot shows, be affected very very little. Exponential decay is very fast!

Comment: Or maybe I should say that a global shift in energy levels has no discernible physical implication. Since it is the electrostatic potential that suffers an arctangent-like shifting, the inner bulk of the semiconductor materials can simply ignore the difference. That is what rigid shifts do.

Answer (score 0):

The explanation of this diagram is given in several books. I will give you a subjective perception of the situation.

At the junction as there are electrons (negative particle) and holes (positive quasiparticle) on both sides, an electric field **E** along the junction axis is created. This explains the formation of so called band bending (at the interface) but merely a band shift far away from the interface.
Now let's take the phenomenon in another very simple way, we dissociate the junction and we apply a weak electric field to both materials in order to have the application of the perturbation theory. We will have the same band diagram without an interface. Holes will be shifted in the opposite direction than electrons and the band energies upshifted for holes (p-type) and downshifted for electrons (n-type).

If the states are almost conserved by this weak electric field, your $E_{c1}$ level does not match at all to the same state after application of the field in the n-type. The previous state corresponding to the $E_{c1}$ energy is downshifted and remains forbidden in the band gap and is **not transformed to an allowed state**. The new $C1$ state in the n-type after the junction was an allowed state downshited in energy.

So your problem is simply a misunderstanding of the shift due to the field and the conservation of these states if the field is weak. As you said band energies should not be taken as absolute values especially if the environment changes.

Comment: Please clarify the geometry of the "split model".  How are the separated parts arranged?  Where is the electric field?   What do you mean by the conservation of states?

Comment: Thanks for the response. If I accept the idea that all the states throughout the material downshift, then the situation makes sense. But how the bands can downshift at all is part of my confusion. As I see it, the "before" diagram says, eg: "an electron cannot occupy a state at EC1 at *any* x position in the N Si." The "after" diagram says: "An electron may occupy a state at EC1 at *any* position in the N Si." Is there physical significance to the fact that Si atoms arbitrarily far from the junction experience this downshift in the allowed energies for their associated electrons?

Comment: Additionally, potentially adding to my confusion, it seems that there are instances in textbooks where the absolute values of allowed energy states are relevant and not only the difference between them. Take for example Zener breakdown where a large reverse bias is applied and the energy $E_V$ becomes allowed in the conduction band. Books will say things like “an electron in the P side valence band ‘sees’ available states at the same energy across the junction and may tunnel into them.” This seems to suggest that the absolute value of an available energy state is also relevant.

Comment: See Fig 4-12 for an example of what I mean here: https://www.chu.berkeley.edu/wp-content/uploads/2020/01/Chenming-Hu_ch4-1.pdf

Comment: @garyp I am not good at drawing but a simple representation would give a field penetrating perpendicularly in the two materials so that one does not screen the other but it remains only a theoretical picture.  Normally at very low perturbation the eigenvalues should not deviate too much from the fundamental state, hence the approximate conservation of these states.

Comment: @knzy I will not comment on your second statement but on the first one it is also a simple theoretical picture  considering the build-in potential as a constant independent of the distance. Rigorously as the potential depends on the distance this schematic representation is not correct.

Comment: For the "before" diagram, you say that "an electron cannot occupy a state at EC1 ...". 
 There are no states at EC1 in the before diagram to occupy.  So I don't follow what you are saying.    Does it help to remember that diffusion due to the difference in carrier concentration across the junction causes a dipole layer to form?   That's pretty much all there is to it.  Carriers gain or lose energy as they cross the junction.

Comment: @garyp Yes, that in “before” no state exists at EC1 is what I meant to say. Is it simply the case that the existence of a potential $V_{bi}$ on the N side relative to the P side necessarily implies that the allowed energy states are elevated by $qV_{bi}$? That is, I’m not completely familiar with the derivation of the allowed electron energy states for an atom, but is it the case that if you somehow assume in that derivation all the electrons are at some potential $V$ then all the resulting allowed energy states are simply shifted by $qV$?